# Postgres table to two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I would like to convert a table with three columns to a two-dimensional array of type `integer[][]`. There are two columns to indicate each of the two dimensions of the array (`x` and `y` in the example) and one `integer` column to indicate the value.

All possible combinations of x and y are accounted for in the data, though it would be nice if a possible solution could substitute `NULL` for missing combinations of `x` and `y`.

The table looks as such:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;

CREATE TABLE t1 (
    x VARCHAR,
    y VARCHAR,
    val INT
);

INSERT INTO t1 (x, y, val)
VALUES   ('A', 'A', 1),
         ('A', 'B', 2),
         ('A', 'C', 3),
         ('B', 'A', 4),
         ('B', 'B', 5),
         ('B', 'C', 6),
         ('C', 'A', 7),
         ('C', 'B', 8),
         ('C', 'C', 9);

SELECT * FROM t1
```

How can I write this query to return a two-dimensional array?

Eg. the result of this specific query should be the following array:

```
SELECT '{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}'::integer[][]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way :

```
select array_agg(dimension1 order by x) as dimension2
from (
  select b.x, array_agg(t1.val order by a.y) as dimension1
  from 
    (select y from t1 group by y) a
  full join (select x from t1 group by x) b on true
  left join t1 on a.y = t1.y and b.x = t1.x
  group by b.x
) a;
```

This is similar and modern one :

```
with 
  a as (select y from t1 group by y),
  b as (select x from t1 group by x)
select array_agg(dimension1  order by x) as dimension2
from (
  select b.x, array_agg(t1.val order by a.y) as dimension1
  from a
  full join b on true
  left join t1 on a.y = t1.y and b.x = t1.x
  group by b.x
  order by b.x
) c;
```

to check if it gives `null` delete one row:

```
delete from t1 where x = 'A' and y = 'B';
```

and you should get :

```
{{1,NULL,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to first group by `x` and use `array_agg()` to get the inner arrays. Then aggregate again using `array_agg()` to get the inner arrays into one outer array.

```
SELECT array_agg(a ORDER BY x)
       FROM (SELECT x,
                    array_agg(val ORDER BY y) a
                    FROM t1
                    GROUP BY x) t;
```